# Diffeomorphic manifolds with the same constant curvature but not isometric

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, curvature

I am looking for a two Riemannian manifolds which are diffeomorphic, have the same constant curvature but they are not isometric.

I thought about the product manifold $(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$, with the diffeomorphism:
$f:(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ given by $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)=(\tan(x_1), \dots, \tan(x_n))$.
Both manifolds have seccional curvature zero, since they are flat manifolds, but they are not isometric ($(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})^n$ is not complete).

Is that example right? Anyway, is there any "more intuitive" example?

Comment: First sentence, first use of "isometric" should be "diffeomorphic"?

Comment: Flat torii, $[0,a]\times [0,b]$ with different values of $(a,b)$. A closed 2-manifold with genus higher than 1 has many different hyperbolic structures on it.

Comment: @Deane Yes, sorry. Edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question, this example is right, and your proof that it is right is right.

But I would say that there is a simpler and more intuitive proof that this example is right: the diameter of $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)^n$ is finite, whereas the diameter of $\mathbb R^n$ is infinite, and "finite diameter" is an isometry invariant.

Of course the *diameter* of a Riemannian manifold $M$ must be formalized, and this is done by defining
$$\text{diam}(M) = \sup_{x,y \in M} d(x,y)
$$
where $d(x,y)$ is the infimum of the lengths of all paths having endpoints $x$ and $y$. This formula yields a value $\text{diam}(M) \in [0,\infty) \cup \{\infty\}$ which is an invariant of Riemannian isometries.